# Can I respond to packets sent to a website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x

I am writing a python program that sends a packet to the server saying 'hello', and I would like to know if I could make my server respond based on it saying 'hello'. My current code for sending a packet is as follows:

```
import requests
hL = 0

HeaderList = [{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 10; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Chrome (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geico) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (Raspberian; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.2 (Windows XP; Intel Windows XP) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Gecko (Bruh; AMD 3600X bruh os) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 42; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (deez; nuts) ooga booga (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'},
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 10; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}]

i = 1
url = 'https://www.whatismyip.com/'
payload = open("request.json")
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    
site = open('site.html', 'w')
site.writelines(str(r.content))

site.close()
print(r.content)
```

I can use HTML and javascript.

Comment: If you owned/operated a server, would you want anyone to be able to inject code into it to  change its behavior?

Comment: @ScottHunter I would prefer not to give anyone access to the server

Comment: @ColinWooldridge Scott's question was hypothetical. It was ment to make you realize that you may be introducing security problems in the way you phrased your question. It appears you are new to webservers. I recommend you look into "escaping inputs", "SQL injection", and "object injection".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is a webserver. Here are a few options:

- [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/): Simple, lightweight, easy to use. I would recommend this to get the hang of things and learn the basics.
- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/): More commonly used and more powerful than the other options listed here. I would recommend this if you want to learn something for professional use.
- [Python's built in http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html): Less user-friendly, less powerful, but requires no external libraries. I would almost never recommend this.

I'll write an example with Flask because its quick, easy, and has a super low barrier to entry. Please note that this would be run separately from your script above as the webserver needs to run as its own process.

```py
from flask import Flask

# Initialize our flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Define our route.
# When somebody accesses /my-route on your website the function below is triggered.
@app.route("/my-route", methods=("GET",))
def sample_route():
    # Technically you should do this from the templates directory and with render_template, but we're learning so we'll do it like this.
    with open("site.html", "r") as f: # Open the file
        return f.read() # Send the contents to the person who visited this route

if __name__ == "__main__": # Standard practice so people can import your file, but this line is not required. Just make sure you don't remove the line below!
    # Run Flask's built-in webserver on port 8080.
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Can be run with `python3 your-script.py`

You can visit http://localhost:8080/my-route in your web browser of choice to see if this worked. In your script you can change `url` to that link as well.

In the example above we are using Flask's built-in webserver, but it is important to know that it is not intended for production use. While you can use it for development you should wrap it with a proper webserver like Apache2 httpd when deploying for prod. [Here's some documentation for that.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/)

Comment: This would work, but thats not what I'm looking for, I would then want Flask to be able to take a packet, read the packet, and respond.

Comment: In my above example Flask is indeed taking the request, reading it, and responding. Do you mean you would like to echo what is sent to it? Ie script: "Hi". Flask: "Hi"? If so you can `from flask import request` and `def sample_route(): return request.data`. As a side note these are HTTP requests, not a single packet. HTTP requests are typically comprised of many packets. I only bring this up because if you are looking to work with low-level packets directly that is an entirely different process.